# using indexOf to search for Strings containing certain letters

Tags: java, indexof

I have written out the following code and my aim is to enter a string at the prompt and return any word in the list containing this string. I think I am only missing something small as when I run the program it prints the whole word list. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package assignment1;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
static List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Please Input A String");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String letters = br.readLine();
    URL oracle = new URL("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18678304/2011/BSc2/words.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        words.add(inputLine);
        in.close();

for(int i = 0; i<words.size(); i++)
{
    if(words.get(i).indexOf(letters) >= 0);
        System.out.println(words.get(i));
}

}
}
```

Comment: I think you need to edit this code.  You have a semi-colon after your if statement, terminating it early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a `;` at the end of your if statement:

```
if(words.get(i).indexOf(letters) >= 0);
    System.out.println(words.get(i));
```

it should be:

```
if(words.get(i).indexOf(letters) >= 0)
    System.out.println(words.get(i));
```

Comment: @TimmjyMorrissey you should really use `String.contains` here.

Answer (score 2):

Braces { } is not required for one statement but it's safer to use always:

```
if(words.get(i).indexOf(letters) >= 0){
System.out.println(words.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this problem should be avoid if he always uses braces in his code.